# Code doesn't run properly and console is restarted in Spyder

Tags: python, console, kernel, spyder

I was running the code below. When I tried to enter non-existing file name, instead of printing out "File cannot be opened", Spyder showed "Connecting to kernel" and the console restarted. How could I fix this? I'm totally new to Python and Spyder.

```
fname=input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhand=open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('Subject:'):
        count = count + 1
print('There were', count, 'subject lines in', fname)
```

Comment: Please post your code, not your image.

Comment: @CeliusStingher: sorry my first time using Stackoverflow

Comment: You need to remove the `exit()` call you added in your code to avoid a kernel restart.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you very much for the explanation. I tried to remove exit(), and the kernel did not restart, but I got a trace back. However, when I ran it in Visual code studio, it worked fine.